# An app to read a value from a known memory address

Tags: android, dump, dumpsys

I Know memory's address in android, that I got using game guardian, let say is AD58DBFC.

I'm trying to read the value from that address in my app, that I will built via android studio further. Is there any method to do that? any adb command or something?

Comment: you need to write native interface search for android jni and then pass this address and exploit xd

Comment: @AkhilaMadari I think the question is clear, maybe you didn't understand what it means. He is talking about main memory aka RAM, not secondary memory aka storage.

Comment: If you know the process number you can probably read/write to its memory using `/proc/<pid>/mem`.

Comment: @m0skit0 Ohh, by referring to "AD58DBFC "  I was not assuming its a RAM. Now its pretty clear  thanks :)

Comment: @AkhilaMadari That totally looks like a memory address to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use any memory editor/viewer. Mentioned GameGuardian for example. Or gdb if you prefer CLI.